# Saving image files from Parse to iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, parse-platform

I have a parse class called `data`, which contains images. My `DetailViewController` contains a `PFImageView` that holds an image from the `data` class and a `UIButton` called `saveButton`.

I would like to save that image into a new folder on the user's iPhone. I've found some related answers, but couldn't utilize them successfully.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFFile *image;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *imageToSave;

- (void) getImageObject {
    // I'm getting the image here, that I want to download and save to the device
    PFQuery *queryObject = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"data"];
    [queryObject whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:self.objectIdent];
    [queryObject getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {

        PFFile *file = [object objectForKey:@"img"];
        // load to the PFImageView
        self.bigImage.file = file;
        [self.bigImage loadInBackground];

        self.image = file;        
    }];
}
// Download and save image to new folder
- (void) getImageFromParse {

    [self.image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"New Folder"];
            // New Folder is your folder name
            NSError *error = nil;
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath])
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:stringPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];

            NSString *fileName = [stringPath stringByAppendingFormat:@"/image.png"];
            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
            [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
            NSLog(@"dev log 2");  
        }
    }];
}
- (IBAction)saveButton:(id)sender {

    [self getImageFromParse];
}
```

This code doesn't generates crashes, just simply nothing happens (the dev log 2 appears in the console), so I don't have any idea why doesn't run it or crash if it's wrong. I would really appreciate any guidance or suggestions, which can help me to solve this issue.

The almost working version, based on walle84's answer: (the only problem is, that it saves the image to the camera roll rather than a new folder)

```
  [self.image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      if (!error) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

        //Saving to app folder
        NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [webData writeToFile:@"my new folders name" atomically:YES];
        //imagePath would your app folder
        //OR if album of iphone then below
        ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
        [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)     [image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
            if (!error) {

            }
                // Success
                 }];
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use below code for getting image from parse.

```
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Your_Class_Name"];
 [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"OBJECT_ID" block:^(PFObject *pfObj, NSError *error)
 {
  if (!error) {
       PFFile *imageFile = [pfObj objectForKey:@"image"];
       [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
          if (!error) {
              UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];  //Got your image

         //Saving to app folder 
              NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);  
              NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
              NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]; //Add the file name to document directory
             NSData *webData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
             [webData writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];    //imagePath would your app folder
         //OR if album of iphone then below
             ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
             [library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)     [image imageOrientation] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error){
                   if (!error)
                     // Success
            }];

         //Best way to create your own folder in album of iphone/ipad.
           [libraryFolder addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:@"YOUR_ALBUM_NAME" resultBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group) 
           {
              NSLog(@"Added folder");
           }failureBlock:^(NSError *error) 
           {
              NSLog(@"Error");
           }];
       }
    }
 }];
```

Also you could have a look at the [documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#files/iOS).

Comment: I got the image, it's not a problem. The problem is that I can't save it to the device.

Comment: save it to album or coredata of your app ?

Comment: I have edited my post so now have a look at it and let me know if anything else you would require.

Comment: @vv88 thanks for vote up but moreover you could also tick my answer.

Comment: Great, it's almost working, the only problem is, that it doesn't creates a new folder, it just save it to the camera roll. I've updated my question with the new code, possibly could you check what could be the problem?

Comment: New question should be a new post and you shouldn't be changing your question in a single post.

Comment: You could use NSFileManager for creating directory. So you have to first check if directory(path) exist or not. If not exist then create it and later save ur image to that path.

Comment: Where did I change my question? I've just updated it with my attempt based on your answer.

Comment: Okay sorry just checked your question and replied for directory stuff in my earlier comment. If anything else do let me know.

Comment: Hey no point in saving images in your app folder rather you could save it in coreData if needed in your app to display to user or you could create your own app name folder in album(iphone or ipad) and save over there. I have updated my post. Give a look !

Comment: I could create a folder in my Photo library, but still can't save the photos there. The `imagepath` should be a string like this: `@"YOUR_ALBUM_NAME"`?

Comment: Ok I will look into it and will post solution or changes asap.

Comment: Got a solution... you could use ALAssetsLibrary+CustomPhotoAlbum files(.h and .m) and follow this [tutorial](http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/ios5-saving-photos-in-custom-photo-album-category-for-download/) but there is a issue that it also saves image to default album so me looking into that and mean while you use it ,and see if it is useful to you.

Comment: There is no way provided for deleting image from camera roll(default album in iOS) so far what I got. For deleting that pic user has to reach out to camera roll album manually. Still I will look for a way to fix or covering up.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (void) getImageFromParse {

    [self.image getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

            ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [library saveImage:image toAlbum:@"New Folder" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        if (error!=nil) {
            NSLog(@"Big error: %@", [error description]);
        }
    }];
            NSLog(@"dev log 2");  
        }
    }];
}
```